# Передача по FIFO USB 2.0. FTDI

Tags: usb, драйвер, fifo, libusb

Имеется устройство ft232h, работающее в FIFO режиме. Использую драйвер libftdi (под linux). Нужно организовать опрос по USB 2.0, в котором сначала посылается короткая команда на ~30 байтов, в ответ приходят два указателя - начало и конец данных для чтения. Потом эти данные нужно считать (~2КБ) Проблема возникает в том, что, как я понимаю, USB на такие короткие сообщения не рассчитан, по крайней мере из коробки, из-за чего эффективная скорость считывания составляет всего около 15Мбит/с. Т. е. частота опроса очень небольшая. В памяти, откуда происходит считывание, эти 2КБ пишутся со скоростью, как минимум, 25МБит/c, а её объем ограничен. Т. е. если замедлить, то новые данные запишутся поверх старых.

Вопрос такой: можно ли как-то увеличить скорость передачи таких коротких сообщений?

Подождать подольше времени - не вариант. Считывание, на данный момент, только постраничное, чтобы прочитать другие 2КБ, нужно устройство переключать на другую страницу отдельной короткой командой.

UPD. Обнаружил возможный источник проблемы: считывание данных происходит только по истечению Latency таймера. Т. е. требуемые байты уже готовы к передаче, но не передаются, пока 1мс не истечет. Хотя, по идее, задержка должна быть 125мкс, т. к. за это время точно ответ из 2Кб сформируются. Почему считывание не происходит - ещё не понял.

UPD2. С помощью wireshark обнаружил, что задержка в 125мкс (что я и хочу), а не в 1мс, возникает, если количество байтов для чтения кратно 512 (с учётом служебных байтов), если, вдруг, это не так, и запрашивается больше, чем можно считать, то возникает задержка в latency time. Теперь остаётся понять, можно ли заставить ft232h отдавать меньшее количество байтов без задержки, или нужно подгонять протокол общения под эти 510 + 2 (payload + служебные) байтов... Драйвер D2XX вроде умеет такую задачу решать, но под линуксом wireshark там какое-то мясо показывает.

Comment: см. `FT_SetLatencyTimer`, вам надо уменьшать это время, общая скорость уменьшится, но будет быстрее переключать направление передачи

Comment: Я сейчас посчитал: фактически скорость 15Мбит/с - это передача 2Кб за 1мс. А драйвер не позволяет ставить latency меньше 1мс, т.е. меньше длины одного фрейма. Уменьшать уже некуда. Но зачем-то же USB 2.0 на микрофреймы бьет данные. Нельзя никак передавать данные микрофреймами по 125 мкс?

Comment: точно не помню, но когда я рассматривал возможность real-time через USB, то упёрся именно в 1 мсек, там какие-то циклы по шине и это ещё как-то с хабами связано и идёт ещё из USB 1.0

Comment: интересная эта штука, она с компа программируется? можно несколько чип селект на неё повесить?